# Concerning the sliding expiration of ASP.NET's forms authentication and session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, asp.net-web-api

We have a ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms application using the native forms authentication and session functionality. Both have a timeout of 20 minutes with sliding expiration.

Imagine the following scenario. A user has worked in our application for a while and then proceeds to do some other things, leaving our application idle for 20 minutes. The user then returns to our application to write a report. However, when the user tries to save, he/she is treated with the login screen, and the report is lost.

Obviously, this is unwanted. Instead of this scenario, we want the browser to be redirected to the login page the moment either authentication or session has expired. To realize this, we have build a Web Api service that can be called to check whether this is the case.

```
public class SessionIsActiveController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value defining whether the session that belongs with the current HTTP request is still active or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the session, that belongs with the current HTTP request, is still active; false, otherwise./returns>
    public bool GetSessionIsActive()
    {
        CookieHeaderValue cookies = Request.Headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault();
        if (cookies != null && cookies["authTicket"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookies["authTicket"].Value) && cookies["sessionId"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookies["sessionId"].Value))
        {
            var authenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookies["authTicket"].Value);
            if (authenticationTicket.Expired) return false;
            using (var asdc = new ASPStateDataContext()) // LINQ2SQL connection to the database where our session objects are stored
            {
                var expirationDate = SessionManager.FetchSessionExpirationDate(cookies["sessionId"].Value + ApplicationIdInHex, asdc);
                if (expirationDate == null || DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() > expirationDate.Value) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This Web Api service is called every 10 seconds by the client to check if either authentication or session has expired. If so, the script redirects the browser to the login page. This works like a charm.

However, calling this service triggers the sliding expiration of both authentication and session. Thus, essentially, creating never ending authentication and session. I have set a breakpoint at the start of the service to check if it is one of our own functions that triggers this. But this is not the case, it seems to occur somewhere deeper in ASP.NET, before the execution of the service.

1. Is there a way to disable the triggering of ASP.NET's authentication and session sliding expirations for a specific request?
2. If not, what is best practice to tackle a scenario like this?

Comment: The best practice would be to stop using server side sessions.  They are a fundamentally broken concept on the web.

Comment: I am aware of this, and we are actually considering eliminating session usage, but even in this perfect sessionless world, the problem would still exist for the authentication ticket...

Comment: Not really. When user-agents are allowed to do the auth handshake properly, the user does not lose their current state.  It is the browser redirecting to a login form that causes the user to lose their work.

Comment: This is unfortunately the way forms authentication in ASP.NET works, when an auth ticket expires the user-agent is always redirected to another, predefined, page. Your suggestions basically suggest that we do not use ASP.NET's forms authentication and session (which, I give you, has some merits to it). However, in the interest of not having to refactor our framework to such a degree, I'm still interested in the answer to my first question.

Comment: Yes, I realize my answer was not directly helpful, which is why I didn't put it as an answer :-) Unfortunately, I can't be any more helpful as I don't use forms auth.

Comment: I believe you cannot disable the session expiry for specific requests. What you might be able to do is to do something at clientside which will keep this session alive. However this is the tradeoff of using Form Authentication. Ideally we should move to cookieless authentication; may be by using some Authentication Tokens.

Comment: @ARS, we're not trying to prevent expiration for specific requests. We want to prevent the renewing of the _sliding expiration_ for specific requests (that have not yet expired).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. This seems to be impossible. Once sliding expiration is enabled, it is always triggered. If there is a way to access the session without extending it, we have not been able to find it.
2. So how to tackle this scenario? We came up with the following alternative solution to the one originally proposed in the question. This one is actually more efficient because it doesn't use a web service to phone home every x seconds.

So we want to have a way to know when either ASP.NET's forms authentication or session has expired, so we can pro-actively logout the user. A simple javascript timer on every page ([as proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15665174/241211) by Khalid Abuhakmeh) would not suffice because the user could be working with the application in multiple browser windows/tabs at the same time.

The first decision we made to make this problem simpler is to make the expiration time of the session a few minutes longer than the expiration time of the forms authentication. This way, the session will never expire before the forms authentication. If there is a lingering old session the next time the user tries to log in, we abandon it to force a fresh new one.

All right, so now we only have to take the forms authentication expiration into account.

Next, we decided to disable the forms authentication's automatic sliding expiration (as set in the web.config) and create our own version of it.

```
public static void RenewAuthenticationTicket(HttpContext currentContext)
{
    var authenticationTicketCookie = currentContext.Request.Cookies["AuthTicketNameHere"];
    var oldAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authenticationTicketCookie.Value);
    var newAuthTicket = oldAuthTicket;
    newAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(oldAuthTicket); //This triggers the regular sliding expiration functionality.
    if (newAuthTicket != oldAuthTicket)
    {
        //Add the renewed authentication ticket cookie to the response.
        authenticationTicketCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newAuthTicket);
        authenticationTicketCookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        authenticationTicketCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        authenticationTicketCookie.HttpOnly = true;
        authenticationTicketCookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
        currentContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationTicketCookie);
        //Here we have the opportunity to do some extra stuff.
        SetAuthenticationExpirationTicket(currentContext);
    }
}
```

We call this method from the `OnPreRenderComplete` event in our application's BasePage class, from which every other page inherits. It does exactly the same thing as the normal sliding expiration functionality, but we get the opportunity to do some extra stuff; like call our `SetAuthenticationExpirationTicket` method.

```
public static void SetAuthenticationExpirationTicket(HttpContext currentContext)
{
    //Take the current time, in UTC, and add the forms authentication timeout (plus one second for some elbow room ;-)
    var expirationDateTimeInUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes).AddSeconds(1);
    var authenticationExpirationTicketCookie = new HttpCookie("AuthenticationExpirationTicket");
    //The value of the cookie will be the expiration date formatted as milliseconds since 01.01.1970.
    authenticationExpirationTicketCookie.Value = expirationDateTimeInUtc.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F0");
    authenticationExpirationTicketCookie.HttpOnly = false; //This is important, otherwise we cannot retrieve this cookie in javascript.
    authenticationExpirationTicketCookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
    currentContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationExpirationTicketCookie);
}
```

Now we have an extra cookie at our disposal that always represents the correct forms authentication expiration time, even if the user works in different browser windows/tabs. After all, cookies have a browser wide scope. Now the only thing left is a javascript function to verify the cookie's value.

```
function CheckAuthenticationExpiration() {
    var c = $.cookie("AuthenticationExpirationTicket");
    if (c != null && c != "" && !isNaN(c)) {
        var now = new Date();
        var ms = parseInt(c, 10);
        var expiration = new Date().setTime(ms);
        if (now > expiration) location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

(Note that we use [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to retrieve the cookie.)

Put this function in an interval, and users will be logged out the moment his or her forms authentication has expired. Voilà :-) An extra perk of this implementation is that you now have control over when the forms authentication's expiration gets extended. If you want a bunch of web services that don't extend the expiration, just don't call the `RenewAuthenticationTicket` method for them.

Please drop a comment if you have anything to add!

Comment: when form auth time out set is 15 minute and SlidingExpiration is true if in that kind of situation any user post data after every few minute say 2 minute then user

login never expire ? tell me. thanks

Comment: does it make sense this line `var newAuthTicket = oldAuthTicket;` from the routine called `RenewAuthenticationTicket()` i guess can we can omit `newAuthTicket = oldAuthTicket` looking for your comment.

Comment: @Mou: 1. Yes, this is how sliding expiration works. 2. If I remember correctly, the line cannot be omitted, because the line below it `FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(oldAuthTicket);` _only_ gives back a result in case the ticket is 'old'. So the assignment you speak of, makes sure `newAuthTicket` always has a value (references something, to be more exact). You can experiment with it yourself to see.

Comment: there is two line 1st one `var newAuthTicket = oldAuthTicket; and second one newAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(oldAuthTicket);` so whatever value will be stored in newAuthTicket the next line will overwrite that....if i am right then what is the meaning of the first line `var newAuthTicket = oldAuthTicket;` not very clear to me.

Comment: I went back and had a better look at it, and you are correct. The line is unnecessary. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The reason authentication cookies are set `HttpOnly` is to prevent an XSS attack from being able to steal your cookie value and hijack your session. By exposing this, you've created a security vulnerability I think. If you want to expose the expiration time to JS, create a separate expiration time cookie and check that instead. I'd welcome a security expert to weigh in on this, but in the meantime be aware that you're explicitly disabling a layer of protection in your security.

Comment: @JT, thanks for your concern. The suggestion you give as a possible workaround, is what is actually already there. The cookie that has `HttpOnly` set to false (`authenticationExpirationTicketCookie`), is in fact a separate expiration time cookie. The actual authentication cookie (`authenticationTicketCookie`) has it set explicitly to true, as you can see in the first code block. So there should be no security concern, agreed?

Comment: @maartendekker you're correct and I was wrong. I'll remove the misleading edit. Thanks for the gentle correction!

Comment: I'm trying to implement this on a vb.net application, as it is exactly what i'm looking for. Question would I need to create the initial SetAuthenticationExpirationTicket when the ticket is initially created on my login page? as old and newAuth tickets always seem to be equal.

Comment: Good point. During login you should always call `SetAuthenticationExpirationTicket`, the process outlined above describes the process from then on.

Answer (score 1):

Your website functionality should work without JavaScript or you just replace one problem with another. I have tackled this problem also and here is how it was solved:

When you authenticate yourself then session cookie is created with default lifetime on 20 min. When this expires user will be logged out.

[image: cookie image]

When user selects "remember me" in the **sign in** form then additional persistence cookie [AuthCookie] is created in client side and in the database. This cookie has a lifetime of 1 month. Whenever page is loaded, session and persistence cookie data is recreated with a new lifetime (normally you want to decrypt/crypt the ticket).

> Imagine the following scenario. A user has worked in our application
>   for a while and then proceeds to do some other things, leaving our
>   application idle for 20 minutes. The user then returns to our
>   application to write a report. When the user tries to save, his session is restored before the request.

One way to do this is to extend global.aspx to handle prerequest. Something in the lines of:

```
    void application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e){
        ...
        if (HttpContext.Current.Handler is IRequiresSessionState) {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                AuthService.DefaultProvider.AuthenticateUserFromExternalSource();
```

AuthenticateUserFromExternalSource should check if cookie data matches with the database one, because anything stored in client side can be changed. If you have paid services with access rights then you need to check if user still has those rights and then you can recreate the session.

Comment: when form auth time out set is 15 minute and SlidingExpiration is true if in that kind of situation any user post data after every few minute say 2 minute then user

login never expire ? tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can all be solved client side, without the need to go back to the server.

In JavaScript do this.

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      window.location = "/login";
 }, twentyMinutesInMilliseconds + 1);
```

The timeout will be set to 20 minutes on every page refresh. This ensures that the user needs to get all their work done before the timeout happens. A lot of sites use this method, and it saves you from doing unnecessary server requests.

Comment: This would be an incomplete solution, it does not take into account that an user can work with the application in multiple browser windows/tabs. Imagine an user working with our application in tabs A and B. When the user requests/posts a page in tab B, the timer in tab A would not be reset and thus get out of sync.

Comment: I agree with you that scenario is possible, but we have no clue as to what the user usage is like from the above question.