# Sliding Session on Web API Request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api2

**UPDATE:** it appears it is trying to write the new cookie header in `ApplyResponseGrantAsync` but can't because it's ***throwing an exception that the headers are already sent.***

**UPDATE:** to be clearer. How do I get the `Set-Cookie` header added to the XHR response during a Web API request?

**TL;DR;** The issue is that the application is authenticated with MVC, but makes heavy use of Web API. The Web API requests do not slide the session even though they use the `Authentication` attribute - almost certainly because it's a cookie response.

I have a combined MVC and Web API application. For the most part, the MVC views just load SPA's that make lots of Web API requests. **This is fine except the session sliding does not work with Web API requests.**

I can see where the `CookieAuthenticationHandler` slides the session in `ApplyResponseGrantAsync`, but I need to force that on every Web API request.

```
model.Properties.IssuedUtc = new DateTimeOffset?(this._renewIssuedUtc);
model.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset?(this._renewExpiresUtc);
if (this.Options.SessionStore != null && this._sessionKey != null)
{
  await this.Options.SessionStore.RenewAsync(this._sessionKey, model);
  ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity((IEnumerable<Claim>) new Claim[1]
  {
    new Claim("Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies-SessionId", this._sessionKey)
  }, this.Options.AuthenticationType);
    model = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, (AuthenticationProperties) null);
}
string cookieValue = this.Options.TicketDataFormat.Protect(model);
if (model.Properties.IsPersistent)
  cookieOptions.Expires = new DateTime?(this._renewExpiresUtc.ToUniversalTime().DateTime);
this.Options.CookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(this.Context, this.Options.CookieName, cookieValue, cookieOptions);
```

Does anybody know how to force this?

### Authentication Setup

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
});

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
```

Comment: my be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629212/concerning-the-sliding-expiration-of-asp-nets-forms-authentication-and-session

Comment: @MikePerrenoud can you add code for your owin pipeline and authentication middlewars?

Comment: @Arvin I added to the end of the question what I believe you're after.

Comment: How has WebAPI been configured in App_Start or Owin (startup.cs)?

Answer (score 2):

According to `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` source, if you set `SlidingExpiration` for `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to true, your session would be renew on every request. You can check this [code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/7cb459795158afe491ae3e6ea9d90a41606fed69/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L244) to see yourself.

<del>I think I track down your problem, based on [this line](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/9c48993a446288032f9824633e6dae81257da06e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs#L101) in order for cookie to renew, the `AllowRefresh` property of `AuthenticationProperties` of SignIn method should be true. I'm guessing this is your problem.</del>

<del>If I'm not wrong you are using  `ApplicationSignInManager.SignInAsync()` in order to sign in your users. Unfortunately based on the [implementation][2] there's no way to pass a parameter to set `AllowRefresh`, So I'm suggesting to override SignInAsync method and set `AllowRefresh` to true, and see if it works.</del>

**UPDATE**

This is another guess, it may solve your problem. Based on [this line](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/7cb459795158afe491ae3e6ea9d90a41606fed69/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L95) a cookie session would renew when only 50% of its lifetime has passed and as I looked at the code I saw no way to override this. I suggest a workaround for renewing cookie by adding a `Middleware` which would `SingIn` user on each request, hence creating a new cookie on each request, and it doesn't matter if the request if in WebAPI or MVC.

Add the middleware after `app.UseCookieAuthentication`

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
},
SlidingExpiration = true,
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
});

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var result = await context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Properties.ExpiresUtc = null;
        result.Properties.IssuedUtc = null;
        context.Authentication.SignIn(result.Properties, result.Identity);
    }
    await next();
});
```

basically you can set `SlidingExpiration` to false, because it don't matter with this workaround and also in this way  `OnValidateIdentity` on `CookieAuthentication` could not reload user Claims every 30 minutes, because IssuedUTC is being refreshed on each request, if you need this you have to modify this middleware and write a custom `OnValidateIdentity`

Comment: Yes, I realize that code executes, however the issue (as stated in the question) is that it doesn't slide on Web API requests.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud I edited my answer, check it if it works

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do the trick. Man, I was really hopeful too!

Comment: @MikePerrenoud I did the same in a new project and it worked for me! Are you using Https / SSL? maybe it has something to do with that. I'm out of ideas!

Comment: It slid the expiration for Web API requests? So in other words, your application made *zero* MVC requests for a page and *only* made Web API requests?

Comment: It slides on both WebApi and MVC requests. Since Cookie Authentication is a Owin Middleware, I think it would slide on every requests

Comment: @MikePerrenoud my application both uses MVC and WebAPI

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty because your answer and help lead me to identify the root cause of the issue - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Generally, it'll work if you enable slidingExpiration in web.config. You have no need to regenerate a new cookie manually. For your scenario, I suggest you to use a trace tool e.g. Fiddler. When you refresh the page, you can check from Fiddler that whether the cookie expired time is reset.

Answer (score 1):

The `ApplyResponseAsync()`, and subsequently `ApplyResponseGrantAsync()` and `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()`, will also be called once when the headers are being written to the client due to the AuthenticationHandler hooking up a callback using `Response.OnSendingHeaders()` during the initialization phase. This makes sure that all handlers have a chance to create a challenge, or handle a response grant, **right before the headers are sent to the user**, *which is the last point in time that we can modify the response*.

<del>*So **Why** you need to build a cookie response in your case?!* Why you don't use a suitable timeout interval (`SlidingExpiration`)? Or at least **use a persistent cookie**.</del>

**Edit**

Some people who have trouble like yours solved by enabling `slidingExpiration` in *web.config* Upon adding the `cookieless="UseCookies"` like the following. Please let me know the result:

```
<forms loginUrl="/account/login" name="authy" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
```

Comment: The issue is that the application is authenticated with MVC, but makes heavy use of Web API. The Web API requests do not slide the session even though they use the `Authentication` attribute - almost certainly because it's a cookie response.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud OK. I have an edition to my answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change things. That's likely because this same initialization was occurring during startup in code.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud I wonder that web API adds some functionalities over HTTP protocol, but here we see something like a conflict !

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Try this: Just add this code to your controller, it is overriding `OnActionExecuted` which runs after every actions and adds the header manually:

```
       protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName=="YourWebAPIName")
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie","CookieName=CookieValue");           
            }
        //You can replace the former if with a more general one like checking:
        //filterContext.Result.GetType() and see if it is of the type JsonResult

            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
```

**------------------Following is my old answer-----------------------------**

First consider @Amirhossein Mehrvarzi questions, if for whatever reasons you need to create your own session sliding consider the following:

*This is just a suggestion, not sure if it will work*

You may try to override either:

`OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` (runs before action)

or `Controller.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)` (runs after action)

operations of the control and slide the session there.

It'll be executed on both WebApi controllersand page controllers, you can know which controller using the `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` as in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=vs.98%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link

both methods will receive useful inputs that can manipulate the action execution as in the following links:

[ActionExecutedContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext(v=vs.118).aspx)

[ActionExecutingContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a filter I had added to the pipeline to log the content of the response. After removing that filter the cookie was being written, even by Web API requests.

```
public class WebApiResponseFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ILogUtils logUtils;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        if (logUtils == null)
        {
            logUtils = StructureMapConfig.Container.GetInstance<ILogUtils>();
        }

        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        var actionDescriptor = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor;

        var requestId = httpContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("X-RequestId").First();
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserName();

        var responseContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content;
        if (responseContent == null)
        {
            logUtils.LogUsage($"RESPONSE LOG ipAddress:{httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress} requestId:{requestId} userId:{userId} userName:{userName} action:{actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName}.{actionDescriptor.ActionName} response:n/a");
        }
        else
        {
            var response = Task.Run(async () => await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
            response = AesManager.EncryptData(response);
            logUtils.LogUsage($"RESPONSE LOG ipAddress:{httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress} requestId:{requestId} userId:{userId} userName:{userName} action:{actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName}.{actionDescriptor.ActionName} response:{response}");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help, and I'm sorry that this little artifact caused the issue!