# How to automatically refresh token in ASP.NET Core 3.0 for API requests?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, cookies, token, openid-connect

I have an `ASP NET Core 3.0` application and I am using `Azure Active Directory` for authentication. Se below autentication configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = auth.Authority;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = auth.SignedOutRedirectUri;
    options.CallbackPath = auth.CallbackPath;
    options.ClientId = auth.ClientId;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied/";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
});
```

The `cookie` is automatically regererated when I change the page after 20 minutes of inactivity, but this isn't happen if I do a call to an `API Controller`. What can I do to automatically refresh token when I do an `AJAX` call and token is expired? Did I foorgot to add something in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189866/sliding-session-on-web-api-request) may give you some ideas - from the previous MS tech stack which followed the same concepts.

You may have some luck with the SlidingExpiration option. Traditionally though this has been a problematic area due to 2 different types of Authorize attribute.

**WIDER POINT**

A cleaner architecture that leads to the most standards based solution with simplest code and best UI control is to avoid mixing Web and API code in the same server side component.

Of course this is probably not in scope for your current project, but for the next one you might consider:

- An ASP.Net Core Web API that validates tokens
- A cookieless Web UI implemented as a single page app
- Web static content hosting
- The UI sends tokens to the API
- The UI silently renews tokens without involving the back end

If interested have a look at my Azure AD sample:

- [Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup)