# ASP.Net - Implementing a Heartbeat Control with multi-tab support

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

### What is it?

The Heartbeat control that I'm currently developing is a client-side/server-side solution which displays a popup modal to the user after 27 minutes of server session inactivity thereby displaying a countdown of 3 minutes before the session expires and returns the user to the Login page. The modal popup also includes an "Extend time" button and a "Logout" button.

[image: Heartbeat modal popup]

### How it works

On the client-side, once the page loads the heartbeat control is initialized and the countdown starts. The heartbeat control has a MaxHealth (milliseconds) and a CriticalHealthRatio (percentage) specifying the session life and when the modal should pop-up respectively.

If the user does nothing during the countdown or alternatively clicks "Logout" then the JavaScript code will redirect the user to the Logout page which clears all sessions and redirects to the Login page.

If the user clicks "Extend time" then an ajax call is made to a web service which simply revitalizes the session on the server-side as well as the client-side's MaxHealth.

### Extending control to be multi-tab compatible

At this point, the heartbeat control works on a page by page basis, but does not take into account other tabs that are opened.

**Scenario 1**: A user logs in and after 15 minutes they open a second tab. Opening another tab will revitalize the session, but the to the first tab the heartbeat is still counting down from that initial MaxHealth, not knowing that the session was in fact reset. Even if the user continues to navigate with the second tab, constantly revitalizing the session, the moment the first tab reaches 0, it will automatically cause the user to be logged out.

**Partial Solution**

In order to solve the underlying problem of causing the user to be logged out on currently opened tabs which aren't being refreshed, my solution was to implement another web service called `GetLastResponse()` that retrieves a session which contains a DateTime value of the last server response time.

Therefore on each page request, the server resets the LastReponse session to the current time which is handled in the Global.asax and the HeartBeat control will now countdown from that LastResponse time when the page is loaded on the client-side.

With this new web service which returns the LastResponse time, I can now simply have the heartbeat control on every tab call it every *X* minutes to determine if the session is any different since the last request thereby synchronizing the Heartbeat controls on all tabs to display the popup at the same time as well as remove the popup on all tabs when the user extends the time on one of the tabs.

But of course, this can't possibly work. The moment I call `GetLastResponse()` the session is effectively reset in the Global.asax.

Even if I add a condition in the Global.asax which doesn't reset the LastResponse session when a request is made to the `GetLastResponse()` web service, that doesn't stop the actual session lifetime from being revitalized; it only disassociates the LastResponse DateTime from the actual lifetime of the session.

### Questions

1. I believe the proposed solution will work, however being that the LastResponse
   and the actual session lifetime will effectively be different, is
   there a better way to go on about this while retaining the core
   functionality intended of the Heartbeat control (synchronized
   countdown, multi-tab extend time, multi-tab logout)?
2. Is there a way to designate a web service to not reset the session
   lifetime when called but also allows C# to access the session?
3. Is there a way to request the remaining session lifetime without
   revitalizing it?

Comment: If you're going to down vote please explain why. I find my question is legitimate due to the lack of material that tackles expanding a typical heartbeat control found on many websites.

Comment: Here is the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14629212/5311735

Comment: @Evk Of course! Storing the LastReponse DateTime in a cookie can alleviate the need to call the `GetLastReponse()` web service effectively bypassing revitalizing the session's lifetime. Well, that's tunnel vision for you. Thanks for the link!